# How do you set sharepoint user field to allow multiple users with powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, sharepoint-list, multiple-values

How do you set sharepoint user field to allow multiple users with powershell?

```
Add-PnPField -List $RecordListName -DisplayName $fieldName -InternalName $fieldName  -Type User -Required -AllowMultipleValues -ErrorAction Continue -AddToDefaultView | Out-Null
```

Tried using `-AllowMultipleValues` but get the below error

> Error: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name
> 'AllowMultipleValues'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add a multi-choice user field, you need to use the `Add-PnPFieldFromXML` method.

Also, the multi-choice user field is a not a simple property. In fact, it's a totally different field type: **Type="UserMulti"**:

```
$fieldXml = '<Field Type="UserMulti" DisplayName="Demo Presentors" List="UserInfo" Required="FALSE" ID="{bd66d0d0-c441-4ce3-909a-204ff01cdcb7}" ShowField="EMail" UserSelectionMode="PeopleOnly" StaticName="DemoPresentors" Name="DemoPresentors" Mult="TRUE" />'

Add-PnPFieldFromXml -List $RecordListName -FieldXml $fieldXml
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass a GUID variable to the xml? I am passing the variable fieldID  and get Add-PnPFieldFromXml : Expected hex 0x in '{0}'.                                                                                                                           
$FieldID = New-Guid
 $fieldXml = '<Field Type="UserMulti" DisplayName="Auxiliary_Admin" List="SiteRecord" Required="FALSE" ID="{$fieldID}" ShowField="Email" UserSelectionMode="PeopleOnly" StaticName="Auxiliary_Admin" Name="Auxiliary_Admin" Mult="TRUE" />'
 $fieldID
Add-PnPFieldFromXml -List $RecordListName -FieldXml $fieldXml

Comment: Sure, the XML is just a string. So you can parameterize it. For example, `... ID=$GUID`